# Get index of element iterating thgrough multiple choices field django for in loop

Tags: python, django

I have MultipleChoiceFieldfield

```
OPTIONS = (
        ("AUT", "Austria"),
        ("DEU", "Germany"),
        ("NLD", "Neitherlands"),
    )

    countries = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"name": "select_0","class": "fff"}),
                                          choices=OPTIONS)
```

I build my own html structure for this field and this is simplified code:

```
{% for value, text in simple_search_form.countries.field.choices %}
   {{value}}
   {{text}}
 {% endfor %}
```

How do I get and index of each element here?
I need to have

```
 {{value}}
 {text}}
 {{index}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's in a for loop, you can use

```
{{ forloop.counter0 }}
```